# Pass current instance to validator in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

In laravel 5.3 can I pass as parameter for rule current instance of model?

I want the rule which checks current value of some field in my model and allows or denies to set this field to another value.

The problem is: validator receives only new value, but I also want to check old value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is still necessary:

You can use fourth argument `$customAttributes` of the static method `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::make`. In this argument you can pass anything you want, in your case - specific instance of the model:

```
$order = new Order(); // <!-- create or load for DB instance of your model

/*
 * create validator for validation of the some $requestForValidation
 * by some $validationRules
*/
$validator = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::make($requestForValidation,
$validationRules, [], [
    'instance' => $order,
]);
```

And in your custom validation rule you can reach this custom attributes like this:

```
Validator::extend('customValidationRule', function ($attribute, $value, 
$parameters, $validator) {
    $validator->customAttributes['instance']; // <!-- here is your instance
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`merge`](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_merge) method to add old value before validation.

```
public function store(Request $request) 
{
     $request->merge(['old_key' => 'Value']);
     $this->validate($request, [
         'old_key' => 'required'
     ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you may be thinking of `exists` validation rule? in Laravel doc: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-exists

Comment: no, I do not need to query database. I want to pass current instance into the validation rule.